# How to copy the value and format of a cell into another cell on Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, format

I have been looking all over the internet for this question, but it has not been answered by anyone.

I am, on Excel 2010, trying to copy (not copy and paste) the format AND value of a cell, onto another cell.

I'm trying to copy my formatted cell (AE1) onto another cell (O3). I have tried to use the `=AE1` function, but it only copies the text. I want the format and the value to be copied however.

All help will be appreciated. :)

Just a note, **I am not copy and pasting. :)**

Comment: Have you used "paste special" when you are pasting the copied cell?

Comment: @ Carl B - I am not copy and pasting. I'm trying to use the `=A1` function, like I mentioned. Did I say something wrong? If I did, my apologies.

Comment: Yeah I don't think you mean copy. You mean use a function to reference the value (and format) of another cell.

Comment: @ Brad Patton - 'xactly. :)

Comment: @Mordecaii - I read it as copy. "I'm trying to copy my formatted cell" - My mistake.

Comment: What you’re saying doesn’t make any sense.  Copying without pasting is like reading an article in the newspaper, then calling your friend on the phone and ***not*** telling him what you read.  In other words, it’s nothing.  Please explain how/why you want to affect a destination cell (based on a source cell) without pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no Excel functions that deal with formatting a cell or using the formatting of another cell. You have to either use UI features like the [Format Painter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/copy-conditional-formatting-HA102809448.aspx) or [Conditional Formatting of cells menu item](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-conditional-formatting-based-on-text-in-a-cell-HA102809699.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102809448). Or you can use VBA to references cells and their formatting.

Excel functions (aka formulas) deal only with values.

Comment: @pnuts true Cell can access some limited formatting info but can that information be used in another cell.

Comment: A bit of a stretch but I can see your point. I will try and add better language in the future.